# Trigger URL WebApp every specific Time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to trigger URL opened in new tab every 10 minutes I tried with this function

```
function openTab() {

var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/...................../exec';

var html = "<script>window.open('" + url + "');google.script.host.close();</script>";

var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open Tab');

}
```

but it can't be triggered on simple trigger or installable trigger

I searched a lot but i'm not sure to execute this

Answer (score 1):

Time-Driven triggers can't open dialogs and sidebars, the alternative is to first open a sidebar to put in it client-side code that will open the dialog.

Related

- [Run script timerbased clientside [GAS]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39347993/1595451)
- [Google Sheets custom sidebar: How to display a current cell value in sidebar without reload the sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57359551/1595451)